# How to force Get-MsolUser return UserExtended?

Tags: powershell, azure

I need to retrieve full user information from MS Azure Active Directory, including passwords.

When using MSOnline PowerShell module, "Get-MsolUser" returns User object.

"New-MsolUser" returns UserExtended which has additional properties (password is among them).

Is there a possibility to get user's password after it was created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't "get" a user's password, you can only set it when creating a new user using `New-MsolUser` or `Set-MsolUserPassword` for existing user. This link will list all properties you can obtain by running `Get-MsolUser`

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn194133.aspx

Comment: Yes, but there is a business logic in the application to send credentials reminder to a user "as is". We had to implement a workaround: duplicate this data on our side.